# ImageMagick Unable to change colour in shade explicitly for image

Tags: image-processing, colors, imagemagick

I want to use **ImageMagick** to change colour in shade.

I am able to manage the shade change using :

```
convert input.png  -colorspace HCL -channel R  -evaluate set 5%  +channel -colorspace sRGB output.png
```

Using **set XX%** i am able to get different colours like, red, green, yellow, blue, pink, sky-blue, gray, etc.

The below command works for  targeting blue colour :

```
convert input.png  -colorspace HCL -channel R -separate +channel -level 48,52% output.png
```

But I am unable to target other colour explicitly.

For example, if I want to change green colour with some other colour, resulted image will effect green, yellow,red and sky-blue as well.

**Is there a way to explicitly change a single colour in shade for :**

- yellow
- sky-blue
- pink
- green
- white
- black
- red

I tried changing all **-channel** : R,G,B,C,M,Y,K,A,O.

Using **-separate** option I can target RBG, but the problem with RGB is R effect red, yellow and pink, G effect green, sky-blue and yellow and B effect blue, pink and Sky-blue.

sample for output :
[RGB image colour change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZnNK.png)

**expected output** : In the above output for "output-0" it effect red,yellow and pink. i want the command which will effect only red. similarly for other colours as well.

links I used : https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33361

I am using python to run this command.  I am also open to use other libraries which will work with all the colours explicitly.

Comment: Please provide a sample image representative of the ones you are using and also show what sort of result you expect.

Comment: I have a bash Imagemagick script that will change individual colors. See my script, huemap, at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html. This is a hue rotation effect. Black and white are not hues, so you won't be able to change those. For that use -fuzz XX% -fill skyblue -opaque white to change white to skyblue. You can also do that for any color as per Mark Setchell's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your image is representative like I requested, it is as simple as this:

[image]

```
magick rgb.png -fill white -opaque red result.png
```

[image]

If you also want to affect hues *"close to red"*, you can apply some fuzz:

```
magick rgb.png -fuzz 40% -fill white -opaque red result.png
```

[image]

Notice that also affects the edges of the red circle where it is a *"feathered red"*.

---

If not, your ImageMagick code is essentially doing a *"Hue rotation"* and, as you have noticed, it affects the entire image. Read the [Wikipedia page on HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) before continuing. Here is an HSI Hue wheel for reference:

[image]

The solution is to do your Hue rotation, but apply its effects via a mask that only selects the colours/areas you want affected. Remember that OpenCV halves the Hue from the range 0..360 to 0..180 so that it can store a Hue in a `np.uint8`.

So, if we load the same image as above and select only the greens (where Hue is near 120) we can rotate just those into blues by adding 60 (Hue=240):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load the image and convert to HSV colourspace
image = cv.imread("rgb.png")

# Convert to HSV and split channels
hsv=cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
H,S,V = cv.split(hsv)

# Shift only greens (Hue near 120) around hue circle by 120 degrees to blues - remembering OpenCV halves all these values - see comment
H[(H>55)&(H<65)] += 60

# Recombine into single 3-channel image and convert back to RGB
result = cv.merge((H,S,V))
result = cv.cvtColor(result,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

cv.imwrite("result.png",result)
```

[image]

---

If you want to change the blues (Hue=240) into yellows (Hue=60), just change this:

```
H[(H>55)&(H<65)] += 60
```

into this:

```
H[(H>115)&(H<125)] -= 90
```

[image]

---

If you want to broaden the range of greens affected, decrease the `55` in my code and/or increase the `65`. If you want to move greens to a different hue, either increase or decrease the `60`.

You can do all the stuff above with PIL/Pillow if you want to - you don't need to install the (massive) OpenCV.

**Keywords**: Image, image processing, Python, OpenCV, ImageMagick, Hue, HSL, HSV, hue rotation, colour replacement, selective colour, mask.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, `H[(H>115)&(H<125)] -= 90` This works, changing the range of **H**, I am able to find the range for Red(-15 to 15), yellow (15-45), green(45-85), sky-blue(85-115), blue(115-145), pink(145-185). But I am unable to find the range for **White, Black** .  what will be the range for Red, white and Black ???

Comment: Red is centred on zero which when wrapped around in a Hue circle touches 360 (i.e. 180), so you need to look for `(H<5)` or `(H>175)`, or you can invert your RGB image and look for cyan.

Comment: Black and white have no hue because they are both unsaturated. So to find Black you need to look for a low Saturation (i.e. no colour) and low Value (i.e. dark). And to find White, you need to look for low Saturation (i.e. no colour) and high Value (i.e. bright).

Comment: The easy way to work out any colour is to crop a lump of that colour out of an image, convert it to HSV and see what you get, possibly with averaging, i.e. `print(H.mean(), H.min(),H.max())`