# Hue conversion in exactly one image

Tags: image

how can i change the Hues of different part of an image at the same time in python ?
for example , convert it's reds to green , and greens to red .

[initial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvFge.jpg)

I have tried SPLIT and MERGE functions , but i didn't get the appropriate results.

```
PEP = cv2.imread("PEP.jpg")
PEP = cv2.cvtColor(PEP , cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(PEP)
```

```
R, G, B = cv2.split(PEP)
img_result = cv2.merge((G,R,B))
plt.imshow(img_result)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saPAs.png)

BUT , the result is not red and it's more like brown ,, which i want it to be red , like initial image .

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please click [edit] and include  a proper, functioning [mcve]. Also, please add, separately, the image you started with, the result you got and the result you expected. Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably find that easier with a *"hue rotation"*. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55982390/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/73956747/2836621

Answer (score 1):

As complementary to @MarkSetchell answers, I would like to suggest a slightly different approach:

Instead of using HSV color space, we may apply the hue rotation in [LAB color space](https://CIELAB%20color%20space).

> The CIELAB color space, also referred to as L*a*b*, is a color space defined by the International Commission on Illumination (abbreviated CIE) in 1976.[a] It expresses color as three values: L* for perceptual lightness and a* and b* for the four unique colors of human vision

The advantage of using LAB color space is the perceptual match to the human vision (the result may be slightly more perceptually accurate compared to HSV color space).

We are going to keep the L (lightness) channel as is, and rotate A and B chroma channels by multiplying each (a, b) "coordinate" by a rotation matrix.
Note that A and B channels are zero-centred, so we don't have to subtract any offset before multiplying.

---

Code sample:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

alpha = 30  # Rotate hue by 30 degrees

img = cv2.imread('input.jpg')  # Read the input image

img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255  # Convert to float for keeping accuracy (float range of pixels is [0, 1])
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  # Convert from BGR to LAB color space
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)  # Split lab channels to l, a and b (2D NumPy arrays).

h = np.deg2rad(alpha)  # Convert alpha to radians

# Rotate (a, b) coordinate of each pixel - multiply by rotation matrix.
# Note: the center value of a and b color planes is defined as 0.
a_out = a * np.cos(h) + b * np.sin(h)
b_out = b * np.cos(h) - a * np.sin(h)

lab_out = cv2.merge((l, a_out, b_out))  # Merge l, a_out, b_out channels.
img_out = cv2.cvtColor(lab_out, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)  # Convert from LAB to BGR.
img_out = (img_out*255).round().clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert from range [0, 1] to uint8 range [0, 255].

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', img_out)  # Write output image.
```

---

`input.jpg`:
[image]

`output.jpg`:
[image]

Comment: Can you please execute both approaches (using HSV and using LAB) and tell if there is a visible difference? It would be nice if you add the output of the two solutions to your post (or at least the HSV output).